# Java Robot screencapture alternative with less latency - Flappy Bird bot

Tags: java, latency, awtrobot

I'm trying to make a bot to play a web based flappy bird game. I have made the following method to play the game:

```
static double play() {
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Rectangle gameZone = new java.awt.Rectangle(11, 108, 522, 620);
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(gameZone);

    double[] data = detection(image);

    double cbx = data[0];
    double cby = data[1];
    double ctx = data[2];
    double cty = data[3];

    if (cby != 0 && cty != 0 && cby != 440.4140316205534) {
        if (cby > 550) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            pause();
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            System.out.println("JUMP 1: " + cbx + " " + cby + " " + ctx
                    + " " + cty);
        } else if (cby - cty > 45 && ctx - cbx < 100) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            pause();
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            System.out.println("JUMP 2: " + cbx + " " + cby + " " + ctx
                    + " " + cty);
        } else if (cby - cty > 75) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            pause();
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            System.out.println("JUMP 3: " + cbx + " " + cby + " " + ctx
                    + " " + cty);
        }

    }

    return cby;
}
```

The method "detection" detects the bird and the center of the space between the tubes. While the performances of screencapture are quite good, just over 30ms for the "play" method to run (so about 30fps), the screen detected seems to be a few hundreds ms delayed.

What I mean is that when the program detects a jump condition and fire the mouse click, the bird has already crashed on the ground. Is there a way to capture the screen in real time in java with almost no delay (a few tens ms are probably acceptable)?

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: If your screen capture is running that fast then it seems like the bottleneck would be in the detection function. (Without even looking at your code i would have guessed that.) your detection algorithm probably needs to be optimized to provide the performance you need

Comment: The whole "play" method takes 32-34ms altogether which seems fine, but it looks like the screen captured by screencapture is delayed by a few hundreds ms.

Comment: You mean you have latency?

Comment: if the detection algorithm is the problem, why not post that code? ;)

Comment: The detection algorithm isn't the problem. The screencapture is.